# Define in external project

Tags: c#, .net-core, preprocessor-directive, explicit

I have 2 project. Nested project have 2 model: `Model1in` and `Model1Out`.

```
namespace Test.Nested
{
    public class Model1in
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1in(Model1Out model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1in();
        }
#endif
    }

    public class Model1Out
    {
#if NATIVE
        public static explicit operator Model1Out(Model1in model)
        {
            return model == null ? null : new Model1Out();
        }
#endif     
}
```

But at other project I want to convert object Model1in to Model1Out and back.

```
#define NATIVE

namespace Test.Native
{
     ....
     Model1Out model = (Model1Out)Model1in;
}
```

The compiler generates an error and does not recognize the model conversion block. Asks to implement. It turns out he just does not see the block `#define NATIVE`. 
What is wrong? I add reference to project `Nested`, `Native` use him and define constant at project settngs.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;NATIVE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If i use this implement for constant at project `Nested` - no problems, but i have other project, where this block cannot be us and i wanna hidden `implicit|explicit` construction.

Comment: "cannot be us" is a hopelessly vague constraint that has no sensible answer.  Get ahead by not doing it this way at all, there's nothing wholesome about it anyway.  Use normal runtime configuration and throw an exception when the conversion operator should not be used.

Comment: @HansPassant i hope to use Define constant at nested project. I wanna to do more then 2 "nested" project with custom explicit function for everyone.

Comment: Very complicated thinking and may prone to hard to detect bugs. Nevertheless, not a bad attempt to understand something better.

Comment: Instead of complicated conversion you may write something trivial like a Debug.Write to see whether you reach #if block at all.

@Riggy should deserve the bounty

Comment: @YauhenKavalenka :-) I understand your frustration. I personally liked the method shown by Riggy. All the best with your project.

Answer (score 3):

I don't completely understand your question.  Are these the steps you are following?

1. Compile `Test.Nested` *without* `NATIVE` defined, creating `Test.Nested.dll`
2. Now in `Test.Native`, add a reference to `Test.Nested.dll`
3. Try to compile `Test.Native` *with* `NATIVE` defined to create `Test.Native.dll`
4. Receive a compiler error that `operator Model1Out()` is undefined

If that is your problem, then here is what is happening.

The `#if` directive is used only when first compiling a project.  If you compile `Test.Nested.dll` *without* `NATIVE` defined, then the code between `#if NATIVE` and `#endif` will not be included in `Test.Nested.dll` at all.  It is as if you compiled  this code:

```
namespace Test.Nested
{
    public class Model1in
    {
    }

    public class Model1Out
    {
    } // I added a missing end brace here
}
```

Your classes are empty, and `Test.Nested.dll` has no conversions defined.

If `Test.Nested` is empty because it wasn't compiled with `NATIVE` defined, then when you compile `Test.Native`, you will get an error regardless of whether `NATIVE` is defined because the conversion block was never included in `Test.Nested.dll`.

In order to use the conversion blocks, you must define `NATIVE` when you compile `Test.Nested`.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Sometimes there are completely different situations, even with certain constants. A similar question was already in the community, but there was a different essence.
See code: https://github.com/ykavalenka/define_test